# Passing Abstract Class Constructor as function parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to pass a reference to Abstract Class Constructor as function param. All works fine for none abstract classes but I can't pass reference to abstract class constructor, anyone knows how to do this ?

```
abstract class AbstractPerson
{
}

function add<T>(provider: new(...rest) => T): void
{
}

add(AbstractPerson);
```

Comment: What is your use case?  You shouldn't try to instantiate an abstract class with `new`, so it rightly does not match the `new(...rest: any[])=>any` signature.  If you are not planning to `new` it, what will you do instead?

Comment: @jcalz Hi, true I am not instantiating it but I am using to create a providers array and I am using abstract class as provider token for the DI, which is pretty convenient.

Comment: I ran into this as well when I was trying to develop a dependency injection system. Interestingly enough, if you just tell typescript to ignore the error ("// @ts-ignore"), it works just fine (as long as you don't try to use the "new" constructor in your "add" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to instantiate an abstract class with `new`, so it rightly does not match the `new(...rest: any[])=>any` signature.  As long as you're not instantiating the abstract constructor, you could try to reference its `prototype` property instead, since it does still have that property:

```
abstract class AbstractPerson {
}

function add<T>(provider: { prototype: T }): void {
}

add(AbstractPerson); // works now
// T inferred as AbstractPerson
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Good suggestion. Are there any other options for the parameter type that would let me use instanceof on it? (i.e. loop through a list and check if any element in the list is an "instanceof providier")

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. I'd do it like this:

```
abstract class AbstractPerson
{
}

function add<T extends AbstractPerson>(provider: new(...rest) => T): void
{
}

class Person extends AbstractPerson { }

add(Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where I needed to pass in an abstract class and then search through a list to find all entries that were instances of a class that extended that base class. I modified Jcalz's answer to allow me to use instanceof in the function:

```
abstract class AbstractObject {
}

function findMatch<T>(provider: { prototype: T } & Function): T {
    let match: T;
    for (const element of object_list){
        if (element instanceof provider){
            match = element;
        }
    }
    // ... do some null check here
    return match;
}

// match is inferred to be type 'AbstractObject'
const match = findMatch(AbstractObject);
```